# Difference in aspect of "Cost/Performance" for Firestore Database functions - setData(from:), setData(from:merge:), setData(from:mergeFields:) (Swift)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I understand the difference between

"setData(from:), setData(from:merge:), setData(from:mergeFields:)",

but only as much as the description says.

I usually used setData(from:mergeFields:) when only a few fields needed update. But recently I was refactoring my code and wondered if I could just use setData(from:) or setData(from:merge:) for every situations.

So my question is: Does it cost more or take more time to update if I use setData(from:) or setData(from:merge:) rather than setData(from:mergeFields:)?

Comment: This seems like something you could benchmark on your own for your specific use case.  Have you tried that?  What are your results?  Do they make sense?

Comment: I am currently testing with 200 test users I've created. I compared A: using setData(from:), B: setData(from:mergeFields:) with no other condition differences. Until now, I couldn't detect the difference in speed. I used my snapshotListener to check the speed of update. I was wondering if the reason I couldn't notice the speed difference is because I don't have a lot of data in each custom object, or is because there actually isn't much difference.

Comment: BTW thanks for the reply. I've received really really a lot of help from your answers in other peoples' questions about Firebase :)